# Merge two Sorted Lnkedlist and print in a new linkedlist

Tags: java, merge, linked-list

I am trying to write codes to merge two sorted list and Display in another List.

I have created a function "Merge" which takes head of each List as its two Arguments and returns head of the new List.I have Created "Display" function which takes "head of the list" to display the Contents inside it.
The problem is when i am trying to display the content of new List ,it displays Nothing.
This is my main Fucntion.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Linkedlist o=new Linkedlist();
        Linkedlist o1=new Linkedlist();
        Linkedlist o2=new Linkedlist();

        o.insertAtlast(5);
        o.insertAtlast(10);
        o.insertAtlast(15);

        o1.insertAtlast(2);
        o1.insertAtlast(3);
        o1.insertAtlast(20);

        o2.head=o2.mergeList(o.head, o1.head);
        o2.Display(o2.head);

    }

}

and this is my Linkedlist Class

public class Linkedlist {

    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node link;
        public Node(int data) {
            this.data=data;
            this.link=null;
        }
    }

    Node head=null;

    public void insertAtlast(int data) {
        Node node=new Node(data);

        if(head==null)
            head=node;
        else
        {
            Node ptr=head;

            while(ptr.link!=null)
                ptr=ptr.link;
            ptr.link=node;
        }


    }


    public void Display(Node node) {
        while(node!=null) {
            System.out.println(node.data);
            node=node.link;
        }
    }




    public Node mergeList(Node head1,Node head2) {
        Node head3=null;

        if(head1==null)
            head=head2;
        else if(head2==null)
                head=head1;
        else {
            while(head1!=null && head2!=null) {

                if(head==null) {
                    if(head2.data<head1.data) {
                        Node node=new Node(head2.data);
                        head=node;
                        head2=head2.link;
                    }
                    else {
                        Node node=new Node(head1.data);
                        head=node;
                        head1=head1.link;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                  head3=head;
                  while(head3.link!=null)
                      head=head3.link;
                  if(head2.data<head1.data) {
                      Node node=new Node(head2.data);
                      head3.link=node;
                      head2=head2.link;
                  }
                  else {
                      Node node=new Node(head1.data);
                      head3.link=node;
                      head1=head1.link;
                  }
                }

            }

        }

        return head;

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

**Recursive Merge :**

```
public Node mergeList(Node head1, Node head2) {
    if (head1 == null) return head2;
    if (head2 == null) return head1;

    if (head1.data < head2.data) {
        head1.link = mergeList(head1.link, head2);
        return head1;
    } else {
        head2.link = mergeList(head2.link, head1);
        return head2;
    }
}
```

Iterative Merge :

```
public Node mergeList(Node head1, Node head2) {

    Node head3 = null, cursor = null, cursorH1 = head1, cursorH2 = head2;

    while (cursorH1 != null && cursorH2 != null) {
        Node temp;

        if (cursorH1.data < cursorH2.data) {
            temp = cursorH1;
            cursorH1 = cursorH1.link;
        } else {
            temp = cursorH2;
            cursorH2 = cursorH2.link;
        }

        if (head3 == null) {
            cursor = temp;
            head3 = cursor;
        } else {
            cursor.link = temp;
            cursor = cursor.link;
        }
    }

    if (cursorH1 != null) {
        if (head3 == null) {
            head3 = cursorH1;
        } else {
            cursor.link = cursorH1;
        }
    }

    if (cursorH2 != null) {
        if (head3 == null) {
            head3 = cursorH2;
        } else {
            cursor.link = cursorH2;
        }
    }

    return head3;
}
```